# How to form a list from queried data?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
            s = (f'{item["Num"]}')
            my_list = []
            my_list.append(s)
            print(my_list)
```

As you can see i want this to form a list that i will then be able to store under `my_list`, the output from my code looks like this (this is a sample from around 2000 different values)

```
['01849']
['01852']
['01866']
['01883']
etc...
```

This is not what i had in mind, i want it to look like this 
[`01849', '01852', '01866', '01883']
Has anyone got any suggestions on what i do wrong when i create the list? Thanks

Comment: Looks like youre in a loop and youre creating a new list each time it loops. Move the creation of the list `my_list = []` to outside of your loop

Comment: Have `my_list = []` once, not in a loop -- and there is no reason to print it all the time in a loop either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first initialize a list here, and then use a for-loop to populate it. So:

```
my_list = []

for values in range(0, #length of your list):
    s = (f'{item["Num"]}')
    my_list.append(s)

print(my_list)
```

Even better, you can also use a list comprehension for this:

```
my_list = [(f'{item["Num"]}') for values in range(0, #length of your list)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your problem and represent this compactly with a list comprehension. Assuming your collection is called `items`, it can be represented as such, without the loop:

```
my_list = [f'{item["Num"]}' for item in items]
```